# Delete the digitally signed signature from pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pkcs#7

i have used an itextsharp tool to sign the pdf with digital signature. I need to know the possibility way of detaching the old signature from the pdf which is signed previously and the same file need to be signed with the new digital signature. I would like to get the response ASAP.

Comment: It's rude to request a response ASAP in a community forum, that kind of requests is reseved to paying support, Don't do it again please. As for your question just delete the signature annotation.

Comment: Extremely sorry for using the word ASAP.

Comment: How to delete the signature annotation?

Comment: @Paulo as the OP immediately wants to sign again, simply removing the value of the signature field might suffice. In that case he can use the resulting empty signature field for the new signature.

Comment: Thanks @Paulo. Can you please tell elaborate me what to be done in code wise.

Comment: @AntonyVimal You might want to indicate how the new signature is to be applied. In particular, does the signing code/service expect an empty signature field and will use it? Or does it always create a new signature field on its own? And you mention one prior signature; do you also have to consider the case of a PDF with multiple signatures? What about changes after signing, shall they be kept? Or might they prove troublesome? To sum it up: You provide way too little information to help you, let alone "ASAP" which as Paulo already explained is inappropriate here.